# java.time.format.DateTimeParseException: Text 'Tue Dec 30 14:28:38 CET 2014' could not be parsed at index 0

Tags: java, string, parsing, date

On a web application I'm working on, I retrieve date as `String` in format like `Tue Dec 30 14:28:38 CET 2014`. I'd like to parse it to Java8 `LocalDateTime`. Below is a summary of my attempt:

```
String string = "Tue Dec 30 14:28:38 CET 2014";
DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss zzz yyyy");
LocalDateTime localDateTime = LocalDateTime.parse(string, formatter);
```

However, it throws the following exception:

> java.time.format.DateTimeParseException: Text 'Tue Dec 30 14:28:38 CET 2014' could not be parsed at index 0

How is this caused and how can I solve it?

Comment: use `SimpleDateFormat`

Comment: same error...java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: "Tue Dec 30 14:52:47 CET 2014"

Comment: use this pattern `EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss z yyyy` may be this should work

Answer (score 2):

Probably the date is invalid for the current language. Month and day abbreviations change from one `Locale` to another.

Check the following example: [ideone demo](http://ideone.com/zzeljx)

```
public static void main (String[] args) {
    String string = "Tue Dec 30 14:28:38 CET 2014";
    try {
        new SimpleDateFormat("EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss zzz yyyy", Locale.ENGLISH).parse(string);
        System.out.println("OK ENGLISH");
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        System.out.println("KO ENGLISH");
    }

    try {
        new SimpleDateFormat("EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss zzz yyyy", Locale.GERMAN).parse(string);
        System.out.println("OK GERMAN");
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        System.out.println("KO GERMAN");
    }
}
```

It's OK when the `String` is parsed using `Locale.ENGLISH` but not with `Locale.GERMAN` (as it should be `"Di Dez 30 14:28:38 CET 2014"`).

If you do not specify a `Locale`, the default is used.